# I can't copy EDITORCONFIG file to other directories

Tags: windows-10, html

I already created a directory with .html and .css files.

Now I want to copy all the files in this directory from my USB key to another USB key, but I've a problem with the .editorconfig file (EDITORCONFIG). I can't copy it to another key, or to other directories on my computer.

So without this file my HTML page:

[image: Website displaying properly]

And here it is after copying:

[image: Website displaying unstyled]

The error code is 0x80070570

[image: Screenshot of copy dialog with error 0x80070570]
"Impossible to copy the file. Unexpected error. If the error persists, is possible to use the error code to search more informations on the problem.

Error 0x80070570: directory or file is damaged or unreadable."

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: "I can't copy it to another key, or to other directories on my computer." What is the error message when you try and copy it?

Comment: `.editorconfig` doesn't affect website's presentation, it only contains some settings for coding style (spaces vs. tabs etc.). Something else is broken.

Comment: @P.Halley Please supply the complete error message. You can use a screen shot if necessary.

Comment: @gronostaj okay thank you, so.. what's the problem? .editconfig is the only file which has an error..

Comment: @Seth I think it's that because without this file my HTML page is broken.. and I copied every other file in my precedent directory.. so if it's not that file, what can I do?

Comment: I've fixed the error screenshot link for you. Please provide translation of the error message. The broken version of website looks like it's unstyled. Check if all necessary CSS files are present in its directory and look for missing file messages in browser's developer tools.

Comment: You could move the file locally in order to verify whenever that reproduces the error locally. If that is the case it would be an indicator that this is actually the reason you're having this issue. Otherwise your markup might be bad or another file is missing or you're doing something fancy that breaks if you move it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows explains what the problem is in the error message:

> Error 0x80070570: **directory or file is damaged or unreadable.**

It sounds like disk's file system is damaged. You should get it fixed ASAP, otherwise it may result in further damage and data loss.

Right-click the disk that hosts the problematic file and open *Properties*. On the *Tools* tab click *Check* in *Error checking* section. Then click *Scan drive*. Windows may complain that it's unable to unmount the drive because it's in use and that scheduling scan to next reboot is necessary, allow it to schedule it and reboot immediately. The scan may take a while (even few hours on HDDs with heavily damaged file systems), don't interrupt it.

You may also want to check your hard disk's SMART status, it's possible that this problem is an early symptom of incoming disk failure.